# SQLite GUIDs not returned on Mac

Tags: macos, sqlite, guid

I have a SQLite v3 database, using GUID's as row identifiers.

Something strange is happening when I query the table on a mac, it returns strange ASCII code in the ID Column where the GUID is supposed to be...

See image: http://i51.tinypic.com/2s0mtyx.png

I've read that it has something do to with BinaryGUID=false setting but not sure...

Comment: What are the reasons for using GUID in Sqlite? Guid is useful in distributed environment let clients generate unique IDs when they can't access DB. When using SQLite you are free from that headache and can use ints.

Comment: I'm not in any position to change the database schema. This is a product database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select hex(Id) from tbIF_PremiumRates
```

I suspect the tool you are using is treating a blob column as text